# How to find the index of multiple columns which qualifies a condition in pandas

Tags: pandas

For a given dataset:
input:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'option1': ['2', '3', '1', '1'], 'option2': ['3', '0', '1', '0'], 'option3': ['1', '1', '0', '0']})
```

I would like to create a new column say 'occur' which follows a certain condition
output should contain new column: `'occur': ['2', '1', '0', '0']`

condition to create 'occur' is to find first index of number which is >2:
1)Lets say for Row1: 3 in option2 column is >2 and its index is 2nd position so 'occur' for row1 will show 2.
2)For second row option1 is >2 hence 'occur' show as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert columns to integers, compare by condition `>2` and get position of first `True` by [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), but then is necessary test if at least one `True` per row by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set `0`, because if not exist `True` per row is returned first column:

```
d = {'option1': ['2', '3', '1', '1'], 
     'option2': ['3', '0', '1', '0'], 
     'option3': ['1', '1', '0', '0']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

m = df.astype(int) > 2
df['occur'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), np.argmax(m.values, axis=1) + 1, 0)
print (df)

  option1 option2 option3  occur
0       2       3       1      2
1       3       0       1      1
2       1       1       0      0
3       1       0       0      0
```

Pandas solution with columns names is similar with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
m = df.astype(int) > 2
df['occur'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), m.idxmax(axis=1), 'not exist')
print (df)
  option1 option2 option3      occur
0       2       3       1    option2
1       3       0       1    option1
2       1       1       0  not exist
3       1       0       0  not exist
```

EDIT: Solution is similar, only select all rows without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = {'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
     'option1': ['2', '3', '1', '1'], 
     'option2': ['3', '0', '1', '0'], 
     'option3': ['1', '1', '0', '0']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
  Name option1 option2 option3
0    a       2       3       1
1    b       3       0       1
2    c       1       1       0
3    d       1       0       0

m = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(int) > 2
df['occur'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), np.argmax(m.values, axis=1) + 1, 0)
print (df)
  Name option1 option2 option3  occur
0    a       2       3       1      2
1    b       3       0       1      1
2    c       1       1       0      0
3    d       1       0       0      0
```

Comment: hi jezrael how can i do it on a pandas dataframe.

Comment: hi jezrael how can i do it on a pandas dataframe.                                                             d = {'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'option1': ['2', '3', '1', '1'], 
         'option2': ['3', '0', '1', '0'], 
         'option3': ['1', '1', '0', '0']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)